# How to fetch targeted results that are related in MYSQL?

Tags: php, sql

Okay so I didn't quite know how to word the question but, I am working on a project and part of the project is supposed to display a history of results for a specific user(The user being a column in the table). My end goal: The user has been banned multiple times and I want to display all of the bans for that specific user. But I can't quite figure out how to do this.

This is the part of code where I want to display the results:

```
<?php
   echo '<li>
            <div>
                <p>'.$row['banDate'].'</p>
                <p>'.$row['banReason'].'</p>
                <p>'.$row['banLength'].'</p>
            </div>
        </li>';
}
?>
```

And I want the result of these rows to be related to .$row['pName'].
Here is my sql Query as well:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = ('SELECT UUID, pName, isBanned, pRank  FROM bans WHERE pName = :pName');
$stmt_1 = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt_1->execute(array(':pName' => $_GET['name']));
$row = $stmt_1->fetch();
```

Ignore the WHERE that is to view each user.

The bans will be stored in a SQL database connected to a Minecraft server. I have tried everything but am still at a dead end.

Comment: Are `banLength`, `banReason`, and `banDate` columns on the table or are they in another table?

Comment: @prodigitalson It's all in the same Table.

Comment: Ok then you need to select those columns as well like `SELECT UUID, pName, isBanned, pRank, banLength, banReason, banDate  FROM bans WHERE pName = :pName'`

Comment: @prodigitalson Okay, I fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns you are trying to use you don't have in your select list so first you need to adjust your query:

```
SELECT UUID, pName, isBanned, pRank, banLength, banReason, banDate 
FROM bans WHERE pName = :pName
```

Then to output all the rows you need to loop over your results or call fetchAll and loop over the array. I would loop over the statement result though since there could potentially be a lot of results and you don't seem to have a reason for fetching them all up front:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT UUID, pName, isBanned, pRank, banLength, banReason, banDate FROM bans WHERE pName = :pName');
$stmt->execute(array(':pName' => $_GET['name']));
?>
<?php if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1): ?>
    <p>No bans for user</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while (false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))): ?>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <p><?php echo $row['banDate'] ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $row['banReason'] ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $row['banLength'] ?></p>
                </div>   
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Now, say I had this same situation but the 3 metoned columns were in a separate table, would I have to create a separate query?

Comment: Depends on the table structure, but likely you would do a single query with a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) like: `SELECT b.UUID, b.pName, b.isBanned, b.pRank, d.banLength, d.banReason, d.banDate FROM bans b JOIN banDetails d ON (d.UUID = b.UUID) WHERE d.UUID - b.UUID AND b.pName = :pName` You just need to have a column that relates both tables to each other either, usually through a formal [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: I seem to be having an issue where no data is being displayed at all.

Comment: You are probably getting an exception or error somewhere... I added output for the exception message but you also should turn on `display_errors`.

Comment: I will double check and get back to you.

Comment: I found the issue, everything is okay. Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: So I am trying to use the single query method, do you think you could explain a little more about that?

Comment: @Flakenstine make a new question and include the tables and columns you need to select from any any other details.

Comment: Here is the new question with other details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311537/php-trouble-associating-results-and-fetching-them-within-mysql

Comment: I also tried to include a lot more information this time.