# PHP - trouble associating results and fetching them within MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

So in a question => [How to fetch targeted results that are related in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576229/how-to-fetch-targeted-results-that-are-related-in-mysql) asked a question on how to fetch results that are related, I got an answer however I have since then changed the formatting.

For my project I have four circles that will display a number on their face as seen here:

```
<div class="front" style="background: #4094ee;">
    100
</div>
```

Now I want to put those numbers to use, for example one of the numbers need to display the amount of times(rows) that a user has been banned. And if the user doesn't exist within the table(has never been banned) then return the number 0.

I got the number to display however it doesn't display the correct number per user name, it keeps displaying the total amount of rows in the table rather than the amount of rows per user if there are rows that exist

```
<?php
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT player_data.uuid, banned_players.uuid FROM  player_data, banned_players WHERE username = :username and player_data.uuid >=  banned_players.uuid');
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_GET['name']));
   } catch(PDOException $e){
    //if an error is thrown a message will display
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
?>
<?php if ($stmt->rowCount() <= 1 ): ?>
0
<?php else: ?>
   <?php while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))): ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The Columns that I need to make use of are
from table

```
   player_data:
       -uuid
       -username
   banned_players:
       -uuid(player_data needs to reference this for each player)
       -permanent(if the player is banned permanently this will return 0 or 1)
       -active(if the player's ban is active this will return 0 or 1)
```

And if it all possible I would like to try to keep from modifying the database tables too much or even at all.

The way the rest of the tables are setup is each user is referenced by their UUID rather than their username. And I am trying to associate the **UUIDs** in each of these tables for the users.

As I mentioned previously I have managed to get a number to display but it is not the number that I want.

So this is the php that I have it's very messy and I am not sure how to fix it, what would be the best solution for what I am trying to accomplish?

Also I apologize if the answer is pretty obvious and clear, I am not too good with PHP, as I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your `UUID` column is a unique identifier (`key`) for a player, thus the values from both tables should be JOINed on this column in the case that the two columns are **equal**.

Given that understanding, you query makes little sense because you are using `>=` for the comparison, making it select the records you want, but also records you do not want. It should be:

```
SELECT player_data.uuid, banned_players.uuid 
FROM  player_data, banned_players 
WHERE player_data.uuid = banned_players.uuid
AND player_data.username = :username
```

Which could also be expressed more obviously as:

```
SELECT player_data.uuid, banned_players.uuid 
FROM  player_data 
JOIN banned_players ON (player_data.uuid = banned_players.uuid)
WHERE player_data.username = :username
```

Comment: Now in the header I need sort of the same thing however I need it to echo out a class name for css that shows if the users ban active(0 or 1) if it equals 0 it will be one color however if it equals 1 it will be another. I can't figure out how do make this work for each time the user is banned.

Comment: If they are currently banned? Because my sense is that `banned_players` is a historical table, meaning that without some other criteria there is no way of knowing if the ban is currently in effect.

Comment: There is a column "Active" that returns either 1 or 0, this tells you if the ban is either banned or not.

Comment: @Flakenstine, yes i realize that, but doesn't this table contain multiple ban entries for a given user, like a log? If so how do you know which one is the most current? Otherwise what is even the point of counting the number of records because there should only ever be one of them.

Comment: Each ban has a release date unless there is only one(In the case that it is permanent)

Comment: Ok... so you need the number of total bans, the most recent ban, and whether or not that ban is active. I that accurate? Is there any other information you need from the ban table?